# Trying to push through cgit

Tags: git, apache, apache2, git-push, cgit

I'm aware that you **can not push through cgit** since it's a frontend to see your git repos. But it can act as a dumb endpoint, allowing to clone for example:
`git clone http://192.168.1.124/cgit/myProject.git/`, once you've done it you'll end up with this remote origin result:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: http://192.168.1.124/cgit/myProject.git/
  Push  URL: http://192.168.1.124/cgit/myProject.git/
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

The problem is when you want to push your changes **you have to change the url**
from: `http://192.168.1.124/cgit/myProject.git/`
to: `http://192.168.1.124/git/myProject.git/`.

I've tried changing the configuration of my *cgitrc* and the configuration from the *apache2* trying to redirect the query using regex but without results.

Do you have any configuration that fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, to be clear, you're looking for an *apache2 configuration setup* that will trick Git into thinking that `git clone http://192.168.1.124/git/myProject.git` is correct so that Git will store `http://192.168.1.124/git/myProject.git` as the origin URL? (Because Git stores the URL you type in.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this apache configuration that works for me. Check for the query and then replace the url.

```
ScriptAlias /cgit/ "/usr/lib/cgit/cgit.cgi/"                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                               
Alias /cgit-css "/usr/share/cgit/"                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                               
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgit/">                                                                                                                                   
        RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                                       
        AllowOverride None                                                                                                                                     
        Options ExecCGI FollowSymlinks                                                                                                                         
        Require all granted                                                                                                                                    
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^service=git-(receive|upload)-pack$                                                                                          
        RedirectMatch "/cgit/(.*)/info/refs" "/git/$1/info/refs"                                                                                               
</Directory>
```